# Can we solve for $a$ and $b$ only knowing the value of $z$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

We have the following equation for $z$ > 0

> $ a^2b+ab^2 = z $

Only the value of $z$ is known. How can we solve this equation to get the values of $a$ and $b$?

Simplifying,

> $ab(a+b) = z $

eg. $z=84$

then $a = 3$, $b=4$

Any approach or suggestions or trial and error method ?

Comment: Here's a tool where you can play with the graphs: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lr7bdb13ca. What conclusion can you make from that?

Comment: There isn't a unique solution.  If $z=0$ then $a=-b$ works for any $b$, for instance.

Comment: Suppose I pick any value for $b$. Can you solve for $a$?

Comment: Must $a,b$ be integers?

Comment: yeah a,b can be integer or float . I need solutions for this equation as solution of general quadratic equations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $a,b,z \in \mathbb{R}$ then there are an infinite number of solutions.

If we assume $a=b$ then we have $2a^3=z \Rightarrow a=b=\root 3 \of {\frac z 2}$.

But if we assume $2a=b$ then we have $6a^3=z \Rightarrow a=\root 3 \of {\frac z 6}, b=2\root 3 \of {\frac z 6}$.

And, in general, if $ka=b$ then $(k+k^2)a^3=z \Rightarrow a=\root 3 \of {\frac z {k+k^2}}, b=k\root 3 \of {\frac z {k+k^2}}$.

On the other hand if $a,b$ are constrained to be integers then you can have zero, one, two or an infinite number of solutions, depending on the value of $z$.

Comment: Good approach, on your last remark depending on value of z we can have infinite solutions for a and b , how can we get those results if there is no relation between a and b ?

Comment: As one of the comments above says, if $z=0$ then any pair $a,b$ where $a=-b$ is a solution. So if $z=0$ there are an infinite number of solutions, even if $a,b$ are constrained to be integers.

Comment: z is not equal to zero z > 0 always

Comment: Then you should add the constraint $z>0$ to your question. Is there any other information that you have forgotten to include ?

Answer (score 1):

Let ${a+b\over2}=:m$. This implies $a+b=2m$ and $2m ab=z$. It then follows from Vieta's theorem that $a$ and $b$ are the roots of the quadratic equation
$$x^2-2mx+{z\over2m}=0\ .$$
This implies that
$$\{a,b\}=\left\{m-\sqrt{m^2-{z\over2m}}, \ m+\sqrt{m^2-{z\over2m}}\right\}\ .$$
If $m<0$ then $-{z\over2m}>0$. We therefore obtain two pairs $\{a,b\}$, whereby the numbers $a\ne0$, $b\ne0$ have different signs.

If $m>0$ we need $m^2\geq {z\over2m}$ in order to obtain real solutions. If $m=\root 3\of{z/2}$ we obtain $a=b=m$, and if $m>\root 3\of{z/2}$we obtain a pair $\{a,b\}$ of different positive numbers.

See the figure linked in Matti P.'s comment.